# How to diagrammatically show this Green's function from a tridiagonal Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

Consider the following electronic Hamiltonian
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\ddots & \ddots &  &  &  \\
\ddots & H_{n-1} & V^- &  &  \\
 & V^+ & H_n & V^- &  \\
 &  & V^+ & H_{n+1} & \ddots \\
 &  &  & \ddots & \ddots 
\end{bmatrix}  $$
where $H_n$ can be a matrix, so mode $n$ can have internal degrees of freedom.

I would like to represent diagrammatically the Green's function of mode $n$. The bare form is something like $g_n=(\omega-H_n)^{-1}$, say, in the frequency domain. Its exact form is presumably given by $$ \tilde G_n^{-1}=g_n^{-1} -(V^-G_{n+1}V^+ + V^+G_{n-1}V^-) .$$ Here, if I am not making any mistake, $\tilde G_n$ is a bit different from $G_{n\pm1}$ due to its two sides of neighbouring modes: $G_{n\pm1}$ are defined only for the respective semi-infinite systems ($m>n$ block and $m<n$ block).

Then how to draw it properly?

Additional: This has the same form as the Floquet theory if $H_n=H_0+n\Omega$ and $V^\pm$ originates from photon absorption/emission. Does the diagram change in this context?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by Green function in this context?

Comment: @lcv Hi, updated with $g_n$. I simply mean the single-particle Green's function.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you define $G_n$ then, as it is not in block form (you need at least two blocks)

Comment: @lcv Sorry, I don't get it. I think the expression of $G_n$ is directly from the Dyson equation of mode $n$. Anything wrong?

Comment: Are there periodic boundary conditions (relevant, for making analogy with Floquet theory). If we really deal with photon absorption/emission, shouldn't the matrix elements contain $\sqrt{n}$ factors? Also, $V^+=(V^-)*$, since the Hamiltonian is Hermitian. Apart from that, interesting problem +1.

Comment: A good way to start solving it is by writing the perturbation series for small $n$ ($n=2, 3, 4...$) and then summing them. One could, e.g., create diagrams with a line corresponding to each state, and the system jumping from one line to another at every transition. The non-diagonal parts are simply the raising/lowering operators.

Comment: @RogerVadim Hi, thanks for the comment. Yes we have $V^+=(V^-)^\dagger$ but not necessarily $\sqrt{n}$ in my experience. My understanding is that the $\tilde G_n$ expression is already the full solution, and one can make perturbations in $G_{n\pm1}$, i.e., starting from $g_{n\pm1}$ till any order. Does it make sense?